# /bin/bash -i overwrites PS1

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

I'm using the following python3.6 code (`g.py`) to launch an interactive bash shell with a customised prompt:

```
import subprocess
import os                                                                         


envi = os.environ.copy() # env of the python process
envi["PS1"]="my-prompt"

s = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i'], env=envi, shell=False)
s.communicate()
```

When I run it on a debian stretch 9 I get:

```
initial_prompt> ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
  206 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
initial_prompt> python3 g.py 
user123§ced47a150f0c:ß$ 
user123§ced47a150f0c:ß$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
  207 pts/0    00:00:00 python3
  208 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
  209 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

I get `user123§ced47a150f0c:ß$` instead of `my-prompt`.

- When I add `--norc` to `/bin/bash` it works, but I need to read `~/.bashrc`.
- In `~/.bashrc`, `PS1` is not changed. I don't have a `~/.bash_profile` file.
- `PROMPT_COMMAND` env variable is empty.
- On MacOS, it works like a charm.

Comment: You will *probably* need to use `--noprofile` and `--norc` to avoid the possibility of any post-startup configuration files from overriding the environment you set. Otherwise, you are at the mercy of whatever those files decide to do.

Comment: I'm not aware of anyway to disable a system-level initialization file without also disabling the user-level one.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `bash` has no system-wide configuration file for interactive shells. But, there is a compile-time option to add one, in `config-top.h`:

```
/* System-wide .bashrc file for interactive shells. */
/* #define SYS_BASHRC "/etc/bash.bashrc" */
```

If this is enabled (as I believe it is in Debian), there appears to be no way to disable this at runtime without also disabling `~/.bashrc`.

Debian's `/etc/bash.bashrc` *replaces* any inherited value of `PS1` with its own value. You can override this, of course, in your own `~/.bashrc`, but it means that you cannot force a value of `PS1` via the environment when starting an interactive shell for someone else. In the end, it's the *user*'s choice what their prompt looks like, not yours.

A workaround might be to provide your *own* rcfile which sources the user's `~/.bashrc` file explicitly, then sets the prompt to what you want it to be. I don't know of any simple way to do this without a temporary file:

```
with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', buffering=True, delete=False) as tmprc:
    tmprc.write('. ~/.bashrc\n')
    tmprc.write('PS1="my-prompt "\n')

    s = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-i', '--rcfile', tmprc.name])
```

Comment: I hd to change the first line to `with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+', buffering=True, delete=False) as tmprc:` But still can't get this to work.  Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Under Debian Stretch, `PS1` is set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

This is also sourced by `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Yes, I've just discovered this line.
`/etc/profile` is run at the launch of all interactive shells ? even those launched by a non-root user ? Is it the first file to be run ? Can we disable that without modifying `/etc` files so the python script works ?

Comment: `/etc/profile` probably isn't relevant; I think `bash` can be configured at compile time to treat `/etc/bash.bashrc` as a system-level equivalent of `~/.bashrc`: if it exists, it is sourced when an interactive shell starts.

Comment: To note: `/etc/profile` should *not* be setting `PS1`, at least not using `bash`-specific features like `\u`, because all POSIX shells use `/etc/profile`, not just `bash`. Ideally, `/etc/bash.bashrc` would only be setting `PS1` if it detected that it weren't already set.

Comment: @machine424 `/etc/profile` should only be run for login shells. I was just pointing out that `/etc/bash.bashrc` is sourced by `/etc/profile`.

Comment: But the user isn't *starting* a login shell, so it's not relevant to the question. The problem is that Debian's `bash` is compiled to source a system-wide configuration file for non-login interactive shells as well.